# Facing issues while calling java method from xslt which uses fop

Tags: java, xslt, apache-fop

I'm using fop to convert xml to pdf, so for that I have written an xslt code.
In the same xslt, I have used java code but somehow I get an error stating nosuchmethodexception : couldn't find method org.apache.xml.utils.NodeVector.input([ExpressionContext,]).

But my java code is a user defined code which is in a different package.

My xml has local_curr attribute.

My java class name is XMLData.
Package is com.pdf
Java Method is input which takes a String value and returns a String

xslt code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:java="com.pdf.XMLData">


    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <!-- Defining Page Layout -->
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A3-portrait"
                    page-height="29.7cm" page-width="40.0cm" margin="2cm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-bottom="20mm" />

                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A3-portrait">

                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

                    <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-width="1mm"
                        border-collapse="separate">
                             <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell background-color="#F79F81"
                                                border-width="0.1mm" border-style="solid">
                                                <fo:block wrap-option="wrap" font-size="15pt"
                                                    padding="5pt" text-align="right">

                                                    <xsl:value-of select="java:input(@local_curr)" />
                                                </fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                                                                          </fo:table-row>
                                              </fo:table>
                                              </fo:flow>
                                              </fo:page-sequence>
                                              </fo:root>
                                              </xsl:template>
                                                                                           </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Does using `<xsl:value-of select="java:input(string(@local_curr))" />` improve things?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `@local_curr` probably does not return the type your java method is expecting.

You need to parse it for example as a string

```
<xsl:value-of select="java:input(string(@local_curr))" />
```

Or as a number

```
<xsl:value-of select="java:input(number(@local_curr))" />
```

The `NoSuchMethodException` was thrown because no method was found with the given type as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.
It is resolved. Actually I have to add my jar file in the batch file of fop which resolved my problem.

Thanks...